# why I am getting The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which should get a directory and process all jpeg files in it using an application that i have.

The batch file is:

```
for %%I in (%1\*.jpg) do (
bin\process.exe %%I "%~dpI\output\%~nxI"
)
```

but when I am running this batch file, I am getting this error:

The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpI\output\%~nxI"

I read the format specifier and it says:

```
%~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
%~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
```

based on it, the syntax should be correct?

What is the problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inside a batch file, you need *two* % symbols when you're using the for loop variables. Variables like %I would only be for the command line. You should be saying

```
for %%I in (%1\*.jpg) do (
    bin\process.exe %%I "%%~dpI\output\%%~nxI"
)
```