# Why am I getting "The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~fA"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

When I run my batch file, which contains :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir %temp% /b /a-d') do (
    echo File Name : %%A, In Folder : %~fA
    )
```

I keep getting the error :

```
C:\Users\Dell User\Desktop>filename.bat
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~fA


For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: is `%~fA` a typo? should be `%%~fA` remember that for `%var` syntax is valid only in commandline context, you must use `%%var` syntax in batch file context.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I thought it was %~fA was because when I tried %~nx0 in a batch file, it worked and printed out filename.bat. Dunno why it happens

Comment: I suggest further to replace `"tokens=*"` by `"eol=| delims="` to process really all files in `%temp%` including those starting with a space or a semicolon.

Comment: Why are you not using, `Echo File Name : %%A, In Folder : %temp%`? The metavariable `%%A`, as you've specified files only and no subdirectories, will contain only file names! And for safety, you should be using `"%TEMP%"`, there's nothing to prevent any user from modifying the location of `%TEMP%` to be on a FAT partition/drive and/or potentially containing space/poison characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why I am getting The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049351/why-i-am-getting-the-following-usage-of-the-path-operator-in-batch-parameter-sub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For` loops are different from just running commands as the `%` sign means something else in a `for` loop. So you have to always escape it with another  `%` sign.

Your code right now is telling Windows command processor that all of the text after `%~fA` is a variable.

If you want to use a variable in it then make always sure to close it with another like this `%%~fA`.